# How do I compress system files for which I have been denied access?

Tags: windows, permissions, compression, file-permissions, system-file

I need to compress some files in a folder, but my system denies me access from doing so.

Since they are system files, how can I compress these files without changing the permissions?

I'm looking for some approach that would in essence *ignore* the permissions, can this be done from the installation medium or do I need to fetch myself one or another boot CD and do it from there?

<sub>*Please keep your do-not-compress-system-files comments at home, thank you!*</sub>

Comment: You may know all the reasons not to compress system files, but for the benefits of others who might read this question: *Do not compress system files*. If you do, you can get into a situation where files that the system needs to read in order to decompress files are themselves compressed, leaving the system unbootable or in various states of unusable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'll debug that case if it would happen. :)

Comment: If it were easy to ignore permissions, then malware would have an easy path to root privileges. You might be able to do it from a ERD commander boot cd, not sure.

Comment: @Moab: Well, inside the OS there surely won't be any easy approach. I was looking for something outside that, it wouldn't be so hard to just ignore the ACL entries and have *full power* access to the disk.

Comment: You'd have to do it external to the OS, so I imagine even the installation medium may prevent you. Is it because the files are ATTRIB +S that you're being prevented? If so, there may not be an easy way around this using built-in utilities.

Comment: @RandolphWest: Worst case I would have to remember the ACL, do a `compact` and write the ACL back.

Comment: You don't need to "remember" the ACL at all. Provided you don't have a long list, Robocopy (I think?) remembers ACLs in a file for you, which you can apply after whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: @RandolphWest: Well, I was referring to some sort of script instead of pure human remembering. Dunno if Robocopy can copy ACLs on its own in some way. But that would be an easy / interesting approach if it worked. In any case, I hope that most files were just in use when I do a second take on this...

Comment: I guessed as much, hence the quotes around "remember". But if I'm right, Robocopy does a pretty good job of recording ACLs. However, it does have a hard limit that I ran into, which escapes me now. I think it was in the thousands.